# How can i publish CSV data as Linked data on Web?

Tags: csv, rdf, semantic-web, type-conversion

My work is mainly focused on conversion of CSV data to RDF data format. After get RDF data ,i need to publish that RDF data as Linked data on web. Actually i want to convert CSV data to RDF data using java programming by myself then i want to publish that RDF data as Linked data on web using any tools.Can anyone help me finding any ways to do this or give me any suggestion or reference ? which tools i should use for this work? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish your RDF in a variety of ways. Here is a common reference where they explain the steps, software tools and examples: http://tomheath.com/papers/bizer-heath-berners-lee-ijswis-linked-data.pdf

In a nutshell, once you have your RDF data, you should think about the following:

1) Which tool/set of tools do I want to use to store my RDF data? For instance, I commonly use Virtuoso because I can use it for free and it facilitates the creation of the endpoint. But you can use Jena TDB, Allegro Graph, or many other triple stores.

2) Which tool do I use to make my data derreferenceable? For example, I use Pubby because I can configure it easily. But you can use Jena TDB (for the previous step) + Fuseki + Snorql for the same purpose. See the reference above for more information on the links and features of each tool.

3) Which datasets should I link to? (i.e., which data from other datasets do I reference, in order to make my dataset part of the Linked Data cloud?)

4) How should I link to these datasets? For example, the SILK framework can be used to analyze which of the URIs of your dataset are owl:sameAs other URIs in the target dataset of your choice.

Many people just publish their RDF in their endpoints, without linking it to other datasets. Although this follows the Linked Data principles (http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html), it is always better to link to other existing URIs when possible.

This is a short summary, assumming you already have the RDF data created. I hope it helps.

Comment: your Comment is effective. Which Virtuoso Version you are using for store RDF ?

Comment: I have been using several after the 6.1 successfully: https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/releases

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tarql (https://tarql.github.io/) or if you want to do more advanced mapping you can use SparqlMap (http://aksw.org/Projects/SparqlMap).
In both cases you will end up having a [SPARQL endpoint](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) which you can make available on-line and people can query your data.
Making each data item available under its URL is a very good idea, following the Linked Data principles as mentioned by @daniel-garijo in the other answer: http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html.
So you can also publish the data-items with all its properties in individual files.